# Installshield 2015 Premier Edition : condition Custom Action to run at end of minor upgrade installation

Tags: installshield, custom-action

In my Installscript MSI project, I'm trying to program a Custom Action to run when a minor upgrade Update.exe has finished installing (After InstallFinalize): 
I assume the Custom Action is always included in the Patch defintion that I create afterward in Media -> Patch Design.

[image]

What do I do wrong please?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on this Stackoverflow question (custom action must be set as Deferred Execution , Absent from Sequence of Install UI Sequence , After InstallFiles of Install Exec Sequence with condition PATCH.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167663/installshield-with-custom-action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167663/installshield-with-custom-action/)

[image]